# Java: Counting Times it takes to generate a given number

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop, nested-loops

So I'm trying to further my knowledge of loops and I'm attempting to satisfy a loop program, ran by a driver.

The final loop to be satisfied should generate a random number between two given bounds, given from the driver, and is to run until the random number is equal to the lower bound. Currently, I'm stuck in an infinite loop.

```
 public void loop4()
{
    System.out.println("Loop 4 Output, lowerBound = " + lowerBound +
                        " upperBound = " + upperBound);

    for(int i = 0;i < 10; i++){ //First loop should take 5 trys
        int num = (int) (Math.random()* (upperBound - lowerBound));
        if(num == lowerBound){
            System.out.println(i);
            break;    
        }
        else{}
    }
    System.out.println("-------------");
}
```

And from the driver:

```
loopTest.setBounds(9, 9);
    loopTest.loop4();

    loopTest.setBounds(100, 200);
    loopTest.loop4();
    loopTest.loop4();
    loopTest.loop4();

    loopTest.setBounds(100, 50);
    loopTest.loop4();
```

So, of course, I'm simply trying to print the counter, i, once num == lowerBound. However, as stated above, I either get stuck in an infinite loop (when I take the limit away from i, in this case it's at ten, just for the sake of testing), or it simply ignore the loop altogether, and I'm having trouble identifying the problem.

Thanks

Comment: _I either get stuck in an infinite loop, or it simply ignore the loop altogether_ That's not possible: your code will have a maximum of 50 iterations in the worst case, there are no conditions to make an infinite loop here

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Random library:

```
import java.util.Random;

public static void loop4()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int lowerBound = 100;
    int upperBound = 102;
    System.out.println("Loop 4 Output, lowerBound = " + lowerBound +
                        " upperBound = " + upperBound);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        // Next line was modified so you get values between lowerBound and upperBound
        int num = lowerBound + rand.nextInt(upperBound - lowerBound + 1); 
        System.out.println(num);
        if(num == lowerBound){
            System.out.println(i);
            break;    
        }
    }
    System.out.println("-------------");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the correct way to approach this problem. Since you are trying to loop an undetermined number of times, calling a method to loop 10 times a piece isn't the best way to solve it.

In this case the "while" loop would be more beneficial, something like:

```
    public void loop4
    {
        int num;
        int i = 0;
        while (num != lowerbound)
        {
        num = (int) (Math.random()* (upperBound - ++lowerBound));
        i++;
        }
System.out.println(i);
    }
```

This way, you only have to call the loop once

Answer (score 0):

upperBound - lowerBound = 50 - 100   for the latest test.
So you'll get a value between -50 to 0 (excluded) and you try to compare it with 100.